# Unable to write tables with "flowable" cells to PDF

Tags: python

I have the following code. How can I make it more dynamic such that:
- I wont have to hardcode/specify the cell width
- HTML Cells should be "flowable" meaning the cell length automatically adjusts depending on the size of the data. Should apply "word wrap" as well 
- Number of columns can vary
- I can fetch data from a database table, convert it to html and write the table to PDF

I tried searching and it looks like the PyFDF has a support for that
http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/PyFPDF-1-54b-HTML-rendering-templates-and-web2py-integration-td2120415.html
but it looks like I have to use web2py. Is there a way to do it without having to use a web framework?

```
import fpdf as pyfpdf
from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin

class MyFPDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    pass

pdf=MyFPDF()

#First page
#pdf = pyfpdf.FPDF(format='letter')
pdf.add_page()
#set the font
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=10)

#define the html text
html = """<H1 align="center">Summary of Transactions</H1>
<h3>Date:</h3>
<h3>Branch:</h3>"""
html += """
<table border="1" align="center" width="100%">
<thead><tr><th width="20%">Date of Transaction</th><th width="20%">Name of Customer</th><th width="20%">Address</th><th width="20%">Contact Number</th><th width="20%">Status</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>cell 1hgjhh jhjhjk jhjfsafsafsafsaf</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4</td><td>cell 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4</td><td>cell 5</td></tr>
"""
html += '<tr><td>' + 'data' + '</td><td>' + 'data' +'</td> <td>' + 'data' +'</td> <td>' + 'data' +'</td><td>' + 'data' +'</td></tr>'
html += """</tbody></table>"""

#write the html text to PDF
pdf.write_html(html)
pdf.output('html.pdf','F')
```

What I'm trying to achieve is similar to the listings.pdf demo here https://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/wiki/Web2Py

Comment: I'm afraid these rather low level PDF APIs require you do to some things "by hand". That doesn't prevent you to write some layout rules as functions, so you can still use your own "framework" with a clean and meaningful API.

Comment: @heltonbiker - I found this one and tried it. It seems to do what I want except that the cell lengths still dont adjust depending on the data

Comment: @heltonbiker - I'm willing to try other workarounds if there are any

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll help but you might want to check out [PyfPDF Templates](https://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/source/browse/Templates.wiki?repo=wiki)